# Why can't NUnit file or assembly be found (C# dll)?

Tags: c#, nunit

Even when my main is empty, I have the following error while loading a C# dll with NUnit:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or
assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.`

I don't understand why it can't find it, I have no clue where to start my search.

Comment: What .NET framework are you targeting, and what is the target of the NUnit version that you are using?

Comment: Did you set the NUnit dll to `copy local` `true`?

Comment: I appreciate both your answer, but I do no know how to check for any one of those? I got a task for a class and we have nothing about those... I'm looking on the net and I'll give you an answer

Comment: ok I copied the dll of NUnit in the folder of my Program.dll and it works! I guess copy local will allow me to skip this part, how could I do it? I have to build it through bash with mcs command

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Reference to `Copy local`, for example:

[image: copy local]

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'm in Xamarin, I'll do it and see if it works!!

Comment: doesn't work.... however it appears to be my problem. I'll add a topic specific to this problem : how to do copy local with mcs (mono) command in bash?

Comment: question is here, if you happen to know the answer, I'd really appreciate it!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620691/how-to-do-copy-local-with-mcs-mono-command-in-bash